# How to improve Apache Spark Multi Layer Perceptron Classifier accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, apache-spark-mllib

I am implementing a multi layer perception classifier using Apache Spark Mllib. As in the code below I have used only two layers which are input layer, output layer. And I get only 33% accuracy.
When I try to add more layers as  `int[] layers = new int[] {36,30,20,13};` I get 27% accuracy.I have tried with various random numbers for layers. But the accuracy is low. Can you help me to improve the accuracy?

```
        int[] layers = new int[] {36,13};
// create the trainer and set its parameters
        MultilayerPerceptronClassifier trainer = new MultilayerPerceptronClassifier()
                .setLayers(layers)
                .setBlockSize(128)
                .setSeed(1234L)
                .setMaxIter(100);
// train the model
        MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel model = trainer.fit(newFrame2);
```

Answer (score 1):

How many features and classes in your dataset have? Usually, the layers in the MLPC is a numeric vector describing the layers in the feedforward neural networks. Each element in the vector gives the size of a layer.

For example, c(4, 5, 2) would imply three layers, with an input (feature) layer of size 4, an intermediate layer of size 5, and an output (class) layer of size 2.

So define your layers accordingly. Hope this helps.